# How to use join() with groupby in pandas data frame so that the values can be separated using a separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, join, pandas-groupby

I am trying to group the data based on "customer no" and also I want to use a customized function that will separate the grouped values with a separator. I know I can use  join(). However, I am not getting the result that I wanted. I am not sure how to modify the code to get the desired outcome. I am getting the grouped values with a separator even though I have used "," separator in my code.

[image: Original data]

Desired output
[image: Desired output]

The code that I have used to do the operation.

```
def f(x):
    return Series(dict(a = "{%s}" % ','.join(x['Date']),
                       A = "{%s}" % ','.join(x['Flag-1']),
                       B = "{%s}" % ','.join(x['Flag-2'])))
new_df1 = new_df.groupby('Customer-Number').apply(f)
```

Kindly help me out with an example. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: try look at groupby with agg join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, what you want to do can be done by:

```
new_df1 = new_df.groupby('Cust no').agg(','.join).reset_index()
```

and if you get an error, maybe you need to change the type of your data before:

```
new_df['Date'] = new_df['Date'].astype(str)
```

Comment: @Deya welcome. please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer as it solves your question.